# In Aurelia, can a slot be used in a repeat.for binding?

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

I'd like to create a custom element that loops through an array and applies the  to each item in the array.  For example, the view template of the custom element would contain something like:

```
<div repeat.for="i of items">
  <div with.bind="i">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I remove the repeat.for and with.bind attributes, the slot displays a single time.  Is there a way to make it repeat for each item in the list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot use slots with `repeat.for` or `bind` today. To do this you have to use replaceable parts. For example:

```
<div repeat.for="i of items">
  <div with.bind="i">
    <template replaceable part="content"></template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<my-component>
  <template replace-part="content">Some Content - ${somePropertyOfI}</template>
</my-component>
```

Runnable example: https://gist.run/?id=29aa1c1199f080c9ba0e72845044799b

Comment: the aurelia blog http://aurelia.io/blog/2016/05/23/aurelia-shadow-dom-v1-slots-prerelease/ says "All the above is implemented with Aurelia. It also works with template controllers such as if and repeat which can dynamically generate content. We've fixed up our @ child and @ children decorators to understand the new model as well."  but it doesn't appear to work

Comment: @MosèBottacini At the time of this answer, it was not possible to use ´repeat` or `bind` with `<slot>`. Explain me what you want to do and I'll try to  give you a solution

Comment: just signaled that probably the documentation is out of sync as it clearly states that it could be done